# Push a View to a Navigation Controller from inside a scroll view (subview)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.ios

What I'm trying to do in paper sounds simple, but I'm actually having trouble doing it

So I'm in this View which has a navigation controller. Inside this view there's a scroll view which I'm pushing a subview to it.

```
        // Setting the View inside the Scroll View //
        viewOffers.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(320f, 1100f);
        ShowOffersViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ShowOffersView") as ShowOffersViewController;
        viewOffers.AddSubview (vc.View);
```

On the SubView, I have a button that I want it to push a view to the NavigationController of it's parent view (main view).

How can I achieve this?

So far I've tried:

```
ChequesViewController test = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ChequesView") as ChequesViewController;

// This     
ParentViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(test, true);

// and this and neither work
NavigationController.PushViewController(test, true);
```

Image Example of what I'm trying to do:
[image: Logic]

Comment: Do you want the view you're pushing to be a subview of the navigation controller, or of the scroll view?

Comment: I want it to push to it's parent Navigation Controller. To clarify a bit: 

[Parent View w/ Nav Controller]
-> [ScrollView with a pushed SubView] -> On button press inside, Push a view to Parent's Nav Controller

Comment: OK gotcha. So the trouble you're having is finding the correct way to reference the navigation controller from within the scroll view. I'm not a Xamarin guy, so I'm not sure I can be of much help, but if you put breakpoints, can you at least find a reference the scroll view's ViewController? If so, then it's `scrollViewsViewController.NavigationController`.

Comment: No problem man, I really appreciate that you're helping. Here's an mock up example of what I'm trying to do. My english is a little iffy (2nd language) but hopefully this explains well. http://oi63.tinypic.com/o527m8.jpg

Comment: Hey did that work or did I miss understand your navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to do this with a event like so:

In Parent ViewController:

```
viewOffers.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(320f, 1100f);
ShowOffersViewController vc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ShowOffersView") as ShowOffersViewController;
vc.ButtonPressed += () => {
    ChequesViewController test = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ChequesView") as ChequesViewController;
    NavigationController.PushViewController(test, true);
};
viewOffers.AddSubview (vc.View);
```

Then in ShowOffersViewController.cs:

```
public partial class ShowOffersViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ShowOffersViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        button.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
    }

    public delegate void ButtonPressedHandler();
    public event ButtonPressedHandler ButtonPressed;

    public void Button_TouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonPressed != null) {
            ButtonPressed.Invoke ();
        }
    }
}
```

Which then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome man, I'm sure it will work! I will try first thing in the morning. Again thanks!

Comment: No worries let me know how it goes